# how to restrict session in a particular domain?

Tags: php, session

I have a web application that's deployed at http://myserver/app1, I've also got another instance of the application that's accessed at http://myserver/app2.

Basically, when I log into app1, I am also logged into app2as. Obviously each instance of the application is identical.

What would be the best way of restricting each instance of the application to be unique and completely independent, so authorization and authentication was applied on each instance individually?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the name that the cookie uses for the second app. If it's using $_SESSION just use [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php). You're going to need to run that before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different session name, but it would be more appropriate to change the domain or path on the session cookie using [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)